# How to run a remote command in PuTTY after login in

Tags: command-line, batch-file, putty, login, plink

in my Windows machine I try to login automatically to remote server (it works) and after then to run commands (i want to reboot it but it does not matter)

I using bat file to log in and run commands:

```
C:\path\to\putty.exe -ssh -load [Sessionname] -l [user] -pw [password] -m C:\path\to\commands.txt
```

or this one

```
C:\path\to\putty.exe plink -ssh -load [Sessionname] -l [user] -pw [password] -m C:\path\to\commands.txt
```

In commands.txt is:

```
echo "hi there"
```

or

```
reboot
```

When I run it console is open and closed, nothing happen.
i think I do some mistake, i read all about this but I cant solve it.
Any help?

Comment: What does this say? `plink -ssh -load [Sessionname] -l [user] -pw [password] -m C:\path\to\commands.txt` (though the combination of `-load` and `-l`/`-pw` is not usual).

Comment: I use this to open session and log in to root: -load [Sessionname] -l [user] -pw [password]

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-cmdline-m.html):

> The `-m` option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see [section 4.18.1](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-command.html#S4.18.1)). However, the `-m` option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.

And quoting section 4.18.1:

> In SSH, you don't have to run a general shell session on the server.
> Instead, you can choose to run a single specific command (such as a
> mail user agent, for example). If you want to do this, enter the
> command in the ‘Remote command’ box.
>
> **Note that most servers will close the session after executing the command.**

The word "instead" means that this is not a command to run in the shell
before passing control to you. This is a command to run
*instead of a shell*.

In your example, the `echo` did its work somewhere unknown,
then the session terminated.

In short, you can't use `-m` for executing commands
*in the remote shell* (because there is none).

Comment: True. But this does not explain why `reboot` does not work.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I don't know in which environment this command executes, but only root can reboot the system. The command should have been `sudo reboot`, but its execution depends on account permissions.

Comment: Hi, remote command box didnt work. So this is why i try to use remote command with -m.

I use this to load session and log in to root:
-load [Sessionname] -l [user] -pw [password]
Maybe my command didnt work because it should not have to?

Comment: The `-m` option is not the right tool for the job.